# Number of files in subfolder of Resources

Tags: objective-c

I've to know how many image are in each subfolder of my Resources folder. I've found this:

```
NSMutableString* bundlePath = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:4];
[bundlePath appendString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];

[bundlePath appendString:@"/MyFolder"];
NSArray *directoryContent  = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundlePath error:nil];
int numberOfFileInFolder = [directoryContent  count];
```

and this:

```
int pants = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/your/path/here" error:NIL] count];
```

What is the best way ?

SOLUTION:

```
int numberOfFileInFolder = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Angry"] error:Nil] count];
```

Pay attention when copying file !!! Don't forget to check "Create folder references for any added folders"

Comment: They're using the same basic approach.

Comment: Have I to replace @"/MyFolder" by the full path ?

Comment: Oh, so your question isn't about counting files.  It's just about computing a path?  Use `[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SubfolderName"]`. Don't use that `-appendString:` method as shown in the first snippet.

Comment: Take a look at my update in original post

Comment: Does not work how? What were you expecting and what did you actually get? And can you describe the layout of the files you are trying to count?

Comment: numberOfFileInFolder = 0 instead of 10...

OP update

Comment: Neither of those paths is your app's Resources. Are those the paths that you want to examine or are you saying that's what your app is actually getting from the posted code?

Comment: You're building an iOS app? Then what can you mean that your "folder really is" on your desktop? Your Resources need to be a part of your app. You need to add the folder (as a folder reference) to your project and have it copied into your app.

Comment: I just want to know the number of images in my subdirectory of Resources named Angry. How can I get this value ? Yes Im on iOS and I've copy all my folder in my app. The location of my App is just on my desktop but that does not mean.

Comment: Pass the address of an `NSError*` variable to `-contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` and check its return code. If it fails, log the error. Also, check your app bundle to see if the resources that expect to be in it actually are.

Comment: Yes resources (images in fact) I want are in my app. I can display them in an another part of my code. But now, I need to know how many images I've in each subfolder of Resources